# Reconnect to mobile via USB without rebooting

Tags: usb, connection-issues

I am a developer (using eclipse) and regularly have my Samsung Galaxy SII connected to my PC via a USB cable. A few times per day I will unplug the cable and plug it back in again in order to take phone calls, go to lunch etc. About 4 times out of 5 this is all fine. But one time in 5 the PC fails to properly re-communicate with my mobile and eclipse does not recognise the phone as being connected. Repeatedly unplugging and replugging in makes no difference, the connection is lost. The only way I know to fix it is to reboot my PC - which takes ages!... Is there something else I could try?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, certainly isn't here with my Galaxy Nexus, you could try an "adb usb" from the CLI? Unless it's the operating system just not detecting it and loading the drivers. Is this a work machine, does it have any software added to not allow unauthorized USB devices?

Comment: Its my own "work" machine. I don't have software that bars unauthorised USB devices. I'll try adb usb next time it happens.

Comment: I've seen that happen on my machine too. I've never been able to reconnect without a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes my computer does the same thing, though it doesn't come up too often. In those cases, I try plugging the device into a different usb port. Usually it fixes the problem (though the first port is still 'disabled' for that particular device until I reboot).